# docker mysql: mysqldump could not create dump file

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu, database-backups

docker mysql: mysqldump could not create dump file.

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3"
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:8.0.33
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
    user: 115:115
    volumes:
      - ./backup:/opt/backup
```

Tried:

```
sudo docker exec mysql mysqldump -u root -p123456  --no-tablespaces --databases my_db > /opt/backup/my_db.sql
```

Error:

```
-bash: /opt/backup/my_db.sql: No such file or directory
```

The directory is there by:

```
sudo docker exec mysql ls -l /opt/backup
```

The owner of the directory is 115:115 (mysql). files can be created under the directory:

```
sudo docker exec mysql touch /opt/backup/foo.txt
```

If dump to current directory without directory "/opt/backup", no error message. But the dumped file could not be found under  root directory. (current directory is root seen by "sudo docker exec mysql pwd").

Similarly, if dump to /tmp directory, no error message, but no file is created under the /tmp.

```
sudo docker exec mysql mysqldump -u root -p123456  --no-tablespaces --databases my_db > /tmp/my_db.sql
```

What is the way to dump mysql data from mysql docker container?

Comment: with `>` you are currently redirecting the output to the host's `/opt/backup/my_db.sql` not within the container

Comment: If you add `ports:` to your database container, you can run `mysqldump` and `mysql` on the host, without special `sudo` or `docker` command wrappers (you do need to explicitly target a TCP port though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `>` you are currently redirecting the output to the host's `/opt/backup/my_db.sql` not within the container

try:

```
docker exec mysql bash -c 'mysqldump -u root -p123456  --no-tablespaces --databases my_db > /opt/backup/my_db.sql'
```